# Xamarin.forms androidx.core.content.FileProvider

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin.forms

```
        <provider
                android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="appp.fileprovider"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true"
                android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

Unresolved class FileProvider. What is problem?

Comment: If you running your application in AndroidX, please read this link and check if you have done the migration. https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/#prerequisites  My nuget package like following screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/zSQ1Ad0

Comment: In visual studio this problem is not observed, but now in Rider it appears. Why can this happen? Did everything according to your instructions